# Progress bar in pyqt not updating properly for reading file

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a progress bar in an app that is supposed to progress as the file gets read but it's not updating at all with my set condition. It seems I need to give the variable responsible for updating the progress bar an explicit value instead of another variable. Please look at the code below, specifically my `loadfile` function.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import subprocess
from time import sleep

class AppView(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(AppView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.buttonStart = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.buttonStart.setText("Start")
        self.buttonStart.clicked.connect(self.start)

        self.progress = QtGui.QProgressBar(self)
        self.progress.setGeometry(200, 80, 250, 20)
        verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        verticalLayout.addWidget(self.buttonStart)
        verticalLayout.addWidget(self.progress)

    def line_count(self):
        p = subprocess.Popen(['wc', '-l', 'xfile'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        result, err = p.communicate()
        if p.returncode != 0:
            raise IOError(err)
        return int(result.strip().split()[0]) #returns 407 lines

    def start(self):
        self.loadfile()

    def loadfile(self):
        x = 100/self.line_count()
        loading = 0

        file_in = "xfile"
        with open(file_in) as f:
            for line in f:
                #sleep(0.1)
                print line
                loading += x
                #loading += 0.245700246
                self.progress.setValue(loading)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    appview = AppView()
    appview.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However, if I set loading like this `loading += 0.245700246` it works. I don't understand why `loading += x` doesn't do the same thing as it also returns 0.245700246.

Another issue is that when it works and the progress bar is updating, the entire UI is frozen. It's like it's using all the ui threads and I don't know how to get around that yet. I cannot close the app or do anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot update your progress bar in main thread, you have to create another one to do that

```
class Progress(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('__updateProgressBar(int)'), 0) ## Reset progressbar value
        file_in = "xfile"
        loading = 0
        with open(file_in) as f:
            fl_content = f.read().splitlines()
            total_lines = len(fl_content)
            for i, line in enumerate(fl_content):
                print line
                self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('__updateProgressBar(int)'), i*100/total_lines)
                sleep(0.1)

class AppView(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(AppView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.buttonStart = QtGui.QPushButton(self)
        self.buttonStart.setText("Start")
        self.buttonStart.clicked.connect(self.start)

        self.progress = QtGui.QProgressBar(self)
        self.progress.setGeometry(200, 80, 250, 20)
        verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        verticalLayout.addWidget(self.buttonStart)
        verticalLayout.addWidget(self.progress)

        self.progressView = Progress()
        self.connect(self.progressView, QtCore.SIGNAL("__updateProgressBar(int)"), self.__updateProgressBar)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def __updateProgressBar(self, percent):
        self.progress.setValue(percent)

    def start(self):
        self.progressView.start()
```

Comment: Do you know how to do the same thing but in python3 and pyqt5?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your example is this line:

```
x = 100/self.line_count()
```

In Python2, `x` will always evaluate to zero, whether you use integer division or not. To get a floating point value, one of the operands *must* be a float:

```
x = float(100) / self.line_count()
```

That change is all that is needed to make your example work. You do not need to use a separate thread, because you are only doing IO operations. Python releases the GIL during IO operations, so the GUI won't be blocked.

Your `loadfile` method can be refined a little more like this:

```
def loadfile(self):
    file_in = 'xfile'
    # no need to call out to wc for line count
    x = float(100) / os.path.getsize(file_in)
    # start at 1 so the progress bar goes to 100%
    loading = 1
    with open(file_in) as f:
        for line in f:
            # use line length to calculate progress
            loading += x * len(line)
            self.progress.setValue(loading)
            # this may help to keep the gui responsive
            QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
```

Comment: Thank you, this clarifies things a lot

Comment: The progress bar is ok but gui is still locked while it works this way.

Comment: @TatakaiWasumi. That's odd, because it work fine for me. If the progress bar is updating, then the gui is not blocked.

Comment: @TatakaiWasumi. PS: I added an extra line to the `loadfile` method which should help to keep the gui responsive.